# MySQL select from UPPER CASE table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a legacy application and am trying to move the MySQL server to a Unix based system (from windows).

My tables are stored as lowercase in MySQL but some of the queries from the application are “select * from UPPERCASE”. This gives me a table does not exist error. I’ve tried making lower_case_table_names=1 and that was not successful.

Is it possible to query with an UPPERCASE table name in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: Now you learn why it's important to respect char casing in programming .. You need to rewrite your qeuries manual..

Comment: Are you sure all your table names are in lowercase? Can you double-check that? When you set `lower_case_table_names=1` *and then restart your mysqld server* the server should downcase all table names. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html Look for a note marked **Exception.**